# Attempting to install postgis getting error : syntax error at or near "postgis_lib_version"

Tags: python, django, postgis

I am attempting to install postgis and trying to integrate it with my django. I am following [this](http://andilabs.github.io/django/devops/tools/postgres/postgis/2015/01/31/postgis-geodjango-english.html) tutorial here. It says the following

```
after connecting to db we need to add geo-extensions:

-- Enable PostGIS (includes raster)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- Enable Topology
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
-- fuzzy matching needed for Tiger
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
-- Enable US Tiger Geocoder
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
check POSTGIS version:

postgis_lib_version();
as a tupple we add it to django settings:

POSTGIS_VERSION = (2, 1, 3)
```

This is what I did

```
mst=# \connect school
psql (10.5, server 10.4)
You are now connected to database "school" as user "mst".
school=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
school=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION
school=# CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION
school=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
CREATE EXTENSION
school=# postgis_lib_version();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "postgis_lib_version"
LINE 1: postgis_lib_version();
```

Any suggestions on why I am getting this error. Anything that I might be missing or doing wrong ??

Comment: There should be a `SELECT` in front of it, can’t just call functions without doing something with their result

Comment: Yup that worked. Thank you. Could you put that an the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling functions there should be a `SELECT` before it or PostgreSQL doesn’t know what to do with the function.

```
SELECT postgis_lib_version();
```